# pclose() prematurely returning in a multi-threaded environment (Solaris 11)

Tags: c, multithreading, solaris, popen

I'm trying to implement a tool that starts 2 ssh connections and executes a script that requires root permission.

Here is a very simple implementation:

```
void* SshConnection(void* args)
{
   char buffer[5000];
   FILE* popenReturn = NULL;

   //get the hostname to connect to
   const char* hostname = (const char*)args;

   snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
           "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x bash -c \""
           "ssh -t user@%s "
           "-i /home/user/.ssh/key.key "
           "\\\"/home/user/DoRootThings.bash\\\" ",hostname);

   popenReturn = popen(buffer,"w");
   pclose(popenReturn);

   //...connect to the host again later on and look at results of DoRootThings.bash...
}
```

I create 2 threads using this function and detach them

Given the above implementation I would  expect 2 gnome-terminals to be visible that have logged into the 'user' account using they keys provided with the -i ssh option. The script should have been executed and is waiting for the root password to be provided while both threads of execution have stopped at pclose() while waiting for their respective gnome-terminals to return.

Instead, 2 gnome-terminals do open and they are waiting for the root password. The execution for 1 of the threads stops at the pclose() while the other threads pclose() immediately returns. This thread then continues onto look at the results of DoRootThings.bash without there being any results since it is still waiting for the password to execute!

Solaris man page for popen() and pclose() claims that they are both thread safe. I have tried multiple forms of locking just to be safe to no avail.

The only form of locking that works is

```
pthread_lock(&lock1);
popenReturn = popen(buffer,"w");
pclose(popenReturn);    
pthread_unlock(&lock1);
```

but this leaves me with a single threaded solution.

Is this a case of the man page being wrong and popen() and pclose() are not thread safe? If so, is there a locking solution that will fix this?

otherwise, am I not doing something correct in my implementation?

NOTE: I initially used system() instead of popen() and pclose() but this is not a thread safe call and the Solaris man page for system() reccomends popen() and pclose()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gnome-terminal` command is probably a poor choice for your example, and I certainly hope it's *just* an example.  It's unclear to me why you're not `popen()`ing the `ssh` command directly.  More on `gnome-terminal` later.

You write

> Given the above implementation I would expect 2 gnome-terminals to be
>   visible that have logged into the 'user' account using they keys
>   provided with the -i ssh option. The script should have been executed
>   and is waiting for the root password to be provided while both threads
>   of execution have stopped at pclose() while waiting for their
>   respective gnome-terminals to return.

, but that's not what *I* would expect.  Calling `pclose()` should first-off close the stream, which the process on the other end will see as EOF on its standard input.  The function will then wait for the child process terminate, but that process should not block on any attempts to read from its standard input.  I would normally expect *both* `pclose()` calls to return quickly.

Now I find it highly questionable to `popen()` a program that presents a GUI, even as simple of one as `gnome-terminal`'s, but I'm inclined to guess that `gnome-terminal` is especially tricky on account of the fact that

> By default, all GNOME terminals share a single process, reducing memory usage.  This can be disabled by starting gnome-terminal with the `--disable-factory` option.

([gnome-terminal manual page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/gnome-terminal/))

I'm sure you can appreciate that that single-process behavior is likely to play havoc with an API that expects to create and manage separate child processes.  I suspect that this is the reason for the observed difference in the behavior of the two calls.

Furthermore, you should check the return values of your function calls, which your example does not demonstrate.  I'm not certain that your `popen()` and / or `pclose()` should be signaling errors, but I'd rate it a good possibility.

Comment: `pclose` will wait for the child process to exit normally; this is required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pclose.html). The gnome-terminal factory is right on the money, I think (very good catch!). The second `popen` will spawn a process that exits very quickly after handing off its workload to the first. If a gnome-terminal is already running, then I'd expect both `pclose` calls to return quickly. Maybe OP can confirm.

Comment: Adding the --disable-factory option to the gnome-terminal has fixed the popen() call returning instantly!

Comment: popening the gnome-terminal made it very easy to get a separate interface to provide the password for the script and see the scripts output. Popening the ssh command directly is definitely a valid solution but would have required more rework.

popen() and pclose() were not returning any errors